# How to access a public property of a username and set a value from web form code behind in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have *UserControl* having

```
public string user_ID{get;set}
```

From aspx code behind, I am calling my usreControl by using *FindControl* since it is in a *LoginView* container.

I need to set a value to **user_ID** property of *UserControl* but I cannot access the property from webform.

Here is my code:

UserControl:

```
public string user_ID { get; set; }
```

.aspx(codebehind):

```
Control userControlForLinks1 =(Control)LoginViewTop.FindControl("NavigationLinksTier1");
if (userControlForLinks1 != null)
{userControlForLinks1.user_ID = currentUser;}
```

Error:

```
'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for user_ID
```

When I give the value as:

```
Tier2:NavigationLinks runat="server" ID="NavigationLinksTier2" linkCSV="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" user_ID ="user"
```

in .aspx page, it works perfect but I have to set it dynamically.

Could you please help me about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, the `Control` class doesn't have any such property.

You need to cast it to a type that actually defines your property

Comment: I am new at coding and trying to learn how to use UserControls. Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: You defined the property in your user control class.  You need to cast to that class.